# Wrong output in yacc and lex programs

Tags: c, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I'm writing code using `yacc` and `lex` check for the syntax of a simple mini C language (C language with very limited functionalities), although the code fails for even a simple C code, which is:

```
int main()
{
   char p;
}
```

**lex code:**

```
%{
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<string.h>
  int yywrap();
%}
identifier  [_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*
%%
"main" {return MAIN;}
"int" { return INT;}
"{" {return *yytext;}
"}" {return *yytext;}
{identifier} { return IDENTIFIER;}
```

**and yacc code:**

```
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int yylex(void);
%}
%token INT FLOAT CHAR IF ELSE BREAK CASE CONTINUE FOR RETURN SWITCH WHILE DEFAULT
%token LE GE NE EQ AND OR MAIN VOID STRINGLIT CHARLIT NUM FLOATNUM IDENTIFIER PRINTF
%% 
 

s : program { printf("valid code"); return 1;}
  ;

program :funcs
        ;
funcs : func
      | func funcs
      ;  
datatype: type
        | VOID
        ;


type    : INT
        | FLOAT 
        | CHAR
        ;
func: datatype IDENTIFIER '(' params ')' '{' statements '}'
    | datatype MAIN '(' params ')' '{' statements '}' 
    ;
params  :   %empty
        |  param params1
        ;
 
params1 : %empty   
        | ',' param params1
        ;
 
param   : datatype IDENTIFIER 
        ;
statements  :   %empty
            |   statement statements
            ;
 
statement: ifStatement|switchStatement|forStatement|whileStatement|declarative|assignment
            | return|jump|expression ';'|compound|printf
          ;
declarative: declstr
             | declnonstr
             ;

declstr: CHAR  declstrlist ';'
        ;
declnonstr: type list ';' {printf("Here bro\n");}
          ;

list : listEntry ',' list
     | listEntry
     ;

listEntry   : var 
            | IDENTIFIER '[' index ']' '=' '{' valueList '}'
            | IDENTIFIER '[' index ']' '[' expression ']' '=' '{' valueList '}'
            | IDENTIFIER '[' index ']' '[' expression ']' '=' '{' valueBlock '}'
            |  IDENTIFIER '=' expression

            ;
var :       IDENTIFIER     
    |       IDENTIFIER '[' expression ']'
    |       IDENTIFIER '[' expression ']' '[' expression ']'
    ';'
```

However the code above fails (`char p ...`), but surprisingly if I put `int p`, instead of `char p`, it works. How is this happening?

Comment: Your lexer never generates a `CHAR` token (nor any other type nametoken  besides `INT`)

Comment: You have `"int" { return INT;}`, but nothing for `"char"`. Is your question really that trivial?